# Correlate NSURLRequest with UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest, nsurlprotocol

In iOS, I'd like to be able to associate an `NSURLRequest`--*any* `NSURLRequest`, whether a navigation request or image or stylesheet request--with the `UIWebView` that sent it. This seems to call for the implementation of an `NSURLProtocol` subclass to capture and analyze requests as they come through. However, I can't find a way to correlate a request with its web view, and `NSURLProtocol` only seems to understand `NSURLRequest`s.

This would be fine for navigation requests, as I could make the association in my `UIWebViewDelegate`. But this won't work for secondary resource requests such as images, which do not trigger `UIWebViewDelegate` methods.

Anyone have any thoughts as to the best way to make this association?

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];           //Create a URL object.
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];            //URL Requst Object
[web loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: If that NSURLRequest garners an HTML response that has, say, img tags in it, the UIWebView will automatically launch secondary requests to retrieve that data. I want to correlate those requests as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could just do `NSURL *url = [[webView request] URL];`

Comment: If I have a webpage on www.yahoo.com that has an image link to maps.google.com, the UIWebView's `URL` property will have no correlation with the URL represented in the image request.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom protocol, canUseProtocol delegate method gets called for referenced resources as well. You may be able to leverage this hook to link your requests, but I am not sure if you can get a failure callback without cancelling that request and performing a separate one with the url.

Your question about referenced resources led me to that discovery, which allowed me to solve a caching problem i was having.

Thank you and I hope this helps in return!